# How to add default header to response in golang gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

How to add default header to response returned in Gin golang? I wanted to add `Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800, immutable` to the every response that I return.

Comment: Have you considered using [middleware](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#using-middleware)?

Comment: nope, how to use it

Comment: Here's an [example](https://github.com/alexander-melentyev/gin-nocache), look at the code to see how it's implemented, look at the readme to see how it's used.

Comment: ok, I look at that code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the above question with following code

```
r := gin.New()

r.Use(func() gin.HandlerFunc {
        return func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.Writer.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=604800, immutable")
        }
    }()
)
```

However, it is not really good idea to add the given header to every request. It is better to add the header to cdn or static items. It can be achieved with NGINX or Traefik.

Comment: I have used it with S3 storage and it is possible to add it there. It is not good place to add this header in gin golang